# PHP Class Inheritance for Beginners

Tags: php, class

```
class User{
    public $company_name;
}

class Employer extends User{
    public $fname;
    public $sname;
}
```

this is the test.php i have created. I have included the class file.

```
$employer = new Employer();
$user = new User();
$employer->company_name = "Company name is ";
echo $user->company_name;
```

When i print the name nothing happens, please let me know what is the wrong with my code.

Comment: You got everything right, just are printing out the wrong value, I think.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive subject.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `Employer` class extends your `User` class but when you create your `$user` and `$employer` objects they are separate entities and unrelated.

Think of your objects like this:

```
$employer = new Employer();
// You now have $employer object with the following properties:
// $employer->company_name;
// $employer->fname;
// $employer->sname;

$user = new User();
// You now have $user object with the following properties:
// $user->company_name;

$employer->company_name = "Company name is ";
// You now have $employer object with the following properties:
// $employer->company_name = 'Company name is ';
// $employer->fname;
// $employer->sname;

echo $user->company_name;
// You currently have $user object with the following properties:
// $user->company_name;  /* no value to echo! */
```

If you want to use inherited properties, it works more like this:

```
class User{
    public $company_name;

    function PrintCompanyName(){
        echo 'My company name is ' . $this->company_name;
    }
}

class Employer extends User{
    public $fname;
    public $sname;
}

$employer = new Employer();
$employer->company_name = 'Rasta Pasta';
$employer->PrintCompanyName();  //echoes 'My company name is Rasta Pasta.'
```

Comment: in php two different class the separate entities meaning even if you call one as super and other class as sub class.

Comment: Great explaination. The OP obviously has it in his head that he is correct.

Comment: @user630320 I can see why you are misunderstanding this, but please be sure that you are.  Your confusion lies in creating 2 different objects of different types.  The way you have written your code, `$employer` is of class `Employer` which inherits class `User`.  However, `$user` is of class `$User` which has absolutely nothing to do with your `$employer` object.

Comment: Thank you, I'm justing getting into php programming, mostly i have done coding in java.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user630320 Just for kicks, try and recode your above PHP classes as Java classes and I am sure you would have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Don't confuse your variables, `$user` and `$employer`, with classes. `$user` is an instance of class User, and `$employer` is an instance of class Employer, but they are separate variables.

Answer (score 3):

You never set `$user->company_name`.

```
echo $employer->company_name;
```

Comment: because user is super class and employer is sub class which means it can use the super class attribute. i dont have to set  $user->company_name because i have already set the $employer->company_name.

Comment: that's not how it works, PHP passes object instances by reference, not the object classes themselves. These are two separate, unrelated instances. If you set a concrete name in the class definition, then all the inheriting classes would have it by default.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't assign something to `$company_name` of object $user; only to $employer.

Comment: because user is super class and employer is sub class which means it can use the super class attribute. i dont have to set  $user->company_name because i have already set the $employer->company_name.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to echo

```
 $employer->company_name;
```

or set

```
 $user->company_name
```

to some value.

You do not have to create an instance of the parent class to work with a child class. In this case, the $employer inherits company_name from the User class.

Comment: I wont to set the values with $employer but i also wont to access from $user can this be done. you now like java where sub class can access the super class attribute

Comment: hello. see response above that the objects are unrelated.