# Can't call function of another class using OOP

Tags: php

I'm a bit rusty with php, I want to know how I can call the function `login` available in `class2`, inside `class1`. This is the example:

```
<?php

    require_once("property2.php");

class Class1 
{
      public function __construct()
      {
         $cls2 = new Class2()
      }

      public function method1()
      {
          $cls2->login() //cl2 is undefined 
      }

} ..

//this is the function

...
class Class2
{
     public function __construct()
     {

     }

     //This is the  function to call

     public function login()
     {
       //Some stuff
     }
} ...
```

Now `PHPSTORM` say that the variable `cls2` is undefined. What I did wrong?

Comment: Should be `$this->cls2`

Comment: What does `Class1` extend???

Comment: @u_mulder I tried in `method1` as `$this->cls2->login()` but I get this error in the network tab: Undefined property: Class1::$cls2 in ... the line that I shown before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Class1 
{
      public function __construct()
      {
         $cls2 = new Class2();
      }

      public function method1()
      {
          $cls2->login() //cl2 is undefined 
      }

}
```

When you create Class1 and call `$cls2 = new Class2();`, `$cls2` exists only locally. You have to make it a class property:

```
class Class1 
{

    public $cls2;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->cls2 = new Class2();
    }

    public function method1()
    {
        $this->cls2->login();
    }

}
```

And then you'll be able to access it using `$this` keyword.

Also please watch for semicolons.

Comment: Oh okay, I understood now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

When you are setting your variable youre not setting it as a class property. Define a `private` variable inside your class, and *"set it and get it"* using the `$this` keyword.

```
class Class1 {
    private $cls2;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->cls2 = new Class2();
    }

    public function method1() {
        $this->cls2->login();
    }
}
```

Another way to achieve this is to use **[Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199862/php-class-inheritance-for-beginners)**, where one class is considered a "parent" class. You would achieve this by using `extends`

```
class Class1 {
    public function __construct() {
        //Some stuff
    }

    public function login() {
        //Some stuff
    }
}


class Class2 extends Class1 {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function method1() {
        $this->login();
    }
}
```